# Creating workbooks with C# and Excel 2007 interop

Tags: c#, excel

i'm curently using Excel 2003 to generate reports, but i'm thinking of migrating to Excel 2007. The problem is that some of my users still have Excel 2003 installed on their PCs, so I'll give them the posibility to choose what to generate - Excel 2007 or Excel 2003 compatible  report. 
So my **question** is : can **Excel 2007** Interop save workbooks in **compatibility** mode ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save workbook as 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214129%28v=office.12%29.aspx
with Format
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241279%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Excel 2003 is probably xlExcel8
http://www.rondebruin.nl/saveas.htm

Answer (score 2):

See [XlFileFormat Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat%28v=office.11%29.aspx), the right choice is:

```
FileFormat: Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel9795
```

If this fails under Windows 7 use:

```
FileFormat: Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can. Just specify FileFormat parameter (second one) of Workbook.SaveAs() method.
You can use any format that is supported by MS Excel. 
List of supported formats is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241279(office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks! and wich one of those would be the excel 2003 compatibility mode ? because the names are very ambigous

Comment: See answer from tom3k. And again, accept ancwer if you like this, otherwise no one will answer you in future.